# Searching for EXACT word in Database using Code Igniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am filtering some data, I have a field called "faculty" and the options are "Professor, Associate Professor, Research Professor" ... so on. My filtering works for every other field but for this specific case I am having trouble because the professor word appears in all the data and as a result, I get all the data that matches the word "professor" so it is not filtering anything. How can I make it to search only for the specific word 'Professor' and avoid getting all the others (research professor, associate professor...)?

// My code

```
function get_search_filters($limit, $start, $search_faculty) 
{
    $this->db->order_by('lname', 'asc'); //order records by last name
    $this->db->limit($limit, $start);

    /* search keyword in all columns*/
    $this->db->like('faculty', $search_faculty);

    $query = $this->db->get('expertise');
    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach ($query->result() as $row) {
            $data[] = $row;
        }
        return $data;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Use `where` instead of `like`.

Comment: add a column "title_id" to your table, where e.g. professor=0 research professor=1 etc... then add a where clause to filter the desired title_id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this->db->order_by('lname', 'asc'); //order records by last name
$this->db->limit($limit, $start);

$this->db->where('faculty', $search_faculty);
$query = $this->db->get('expertise');
```

https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#looking-for-specific-data

Comment: Thank you, it totally slipped my mind that 'where' existed

Comment: There are some exceptions, but generally speaking `where` will perform much better on indexed fields than `like`